compiler options -c-isystem, -cxx-isystem, -internal-isystem, -internal-externc-isystem
When I research every option for the compiler working, I notice that here exists some options I never heard before even hard to realize what exactly functions they make. So I hope here will be some easy-to-learning explanations to help me understand how they work. Thanks a lot.
Try to ask GPT Plus but hardly to acquire useful information.
Could have some little demos for using these?
Relative options:

-c-isystem
-cxx-isystem
-internal-isystem
-internal-externc-isystem


Which options? for using these? Which ones? I notice that here exists Where "here"?

Sorry sir, I included them in title, here I post these options again.
-c-isystem, -cxx-isystem, -internal-isystem, internal-externc-isystem

What parts of the documentation for these options do you need help understanding?

There are no such options in gcc. I notice that here exists again, "where" is "here"? Where did you notice it? how they work? What exactly is unclear in how they work? Do you understand what "add a path to include search path" means? See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#include-path-management .

Thanks a lot, I may should notice there are some differences from gcc and clang options and add tag carefully.
